# Splitting dataset

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, machine-learning

I am new to opencv and python.

I am trying to create sudoku solver in opencv and want to use this image as my dataset for recognizing the digits in sudoku. 
I want the entire image to be used as dataset.

[sudoku digits dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4364.png)

Dimensions: 468x108

This image has 39 numbers in a row and 9 such rows [ 1 .. 9 ]

```
image = cv2.imread( 'images/digits_sudoku4.png')

image = cv2.resize( image, None, fx=2, fy=2,)
gray = cv2.cvtColor( image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


cells = [np.hsplit(row, 39) for row in np.vsplit(gray, 12)]

# Convert the List data type to Numpy Array
x = np.array(cells)
print ("The shape of our cells array: " + str(x.shape))


train = x.astype(np.float32)  # Size = (3500,400)
# Create labels for train and test data
k = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
train_labels = np.repeat( k, 468)[:, np.newaxis]


# Initiate kNN, train the data, then test it with test data for k=3
knn = cv2.KNearest()
knn.train(train, train_labels)
#ret, result, neighbors, distance = knn.find_nearest(test, k=3)

# Now we check the accuracy of classification
# For that, compare the result with test_labels and check which are wrong
'''
matches = result == test_labels
correct = np.count_nonzero(matches)
accuracy = correct * (100.0 / result.size)
print("Accuracy is = %.2f" % accuracy + "%")
'''


cv2.imshow( 'Sudoku', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am facing this error on line knn.train(train, train_labels)...

```
cv2.error: /build/opencv-SviWsf/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:857: error: (-5) train data must be floating-point matrix in function cvCheckTrainData
```

Please help me out.

Thankyou.

Comment: Here is my result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezThF.png There are may error in your code, such as dimensions. And I use `OpenCV 3.3`, the API also changed.

Comment: Awesome  ...Please share your code 